# Four labels and text boxes in same row at a definite space between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

How to make following four labels and text boxes in same row at a particular distance between elements.I used float left in  `editor-label` and `editor-field`  but they are coming at random distances

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("firstname")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("txtname")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label("lastname")</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
 @Html.TextBox("txtlname")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label("age")</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
 @Html.TextBox("txtlage")
    </div>
       <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label("salary")</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
 @Html.TextBox("txtsalary")
    </div>
```

Comment: @humble.rumble in css i just added float:left

Comment: @humble.rumble  definite space between means 10 % between label and textbox and 20 % between textbox and next label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a child elements margin/padding to a percentage of the grandparent. You can however, use `vw` css units which refer to a percentage of the viewport width. so `10vw` would be 10% of the browsers width.

Unfortunately, if the container of your form line is not the same width as the browser window you could run into issues.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/2seLh37m/2/embedded/result/))

```css
.form-line {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.form-line div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20vw;
}
.form-line div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.form-line div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.form-line div label {
    margin-right: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-line">
    <div>
        <label for="text1">First Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="text1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="text2">Second Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="text2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="text3">Third Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="text3">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="text4">Fourth Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="text4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is showing flex is not a valid property for display and even justify-content also.Will this support html5 i am using asp.net mvc4 which emits html5

Comment: @ humble.rumble it is working fine ,thanks, but can i put some definite space like 20 % between textbox and next lablel and 10 % between label and textbox